# Uncaught PHP Exception: "No route found for "GET /src/Controller/TaskNeedsController.php"" at /RouterListener.php line 136

Tags: php, symfony

So I inherited some code at my current position that I am having trouble modifying. The code is supposed to take data from a table and send an email out to the responsible clinician that the task needs to be completed. It uses Symfony to accomplish this. When the code runs I get the following error.

[Exceptions shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibBCL.png)

The error in the logs shows

```
10:56:44
request Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for 
"GET /src/Controller/TaskNeedsController.php"" at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 136
{
    "exception": {}
}
```

I haven't touched either files that would affect this and I'm unsure as to why these errors are coming up.

In Stack Traces it gives me

```
No route found for "GET /src/Controller/TaskNeedsController.php"

  at vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:136
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(object(RequestEvent), 'kernel.request', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
     (vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:126)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener->__invoke(object(RequestEvent), 'kernel.request', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
     (vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:264)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.request', object(RequestEvent))
     (vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:239)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->callListeners(array(object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.request', object(RequestEvent))
     (vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:73)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch(object(RequestEvent), 'kernel.request')
     (vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:168)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch(object(RequestEvent), 'kernel.request')
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:122)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:68)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:201)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (public/index.php:37)
```

And

```
No routes found for "/src/Controller/TaskNeedsController.php/".

  at vendor/symfony/routing/Matcher/Dumper/CompiledUrlMatcherTrait.php:70
  at Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\CompiledUrlMatcher->match('/src/Controller/TaskNeedsController.php/')
     (vendor/symfony/routing/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php:106)
  at Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher->matchRequest(object(Request))
     (vendor/symfony/routing/Router.php:274)
  at Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->matchRequest(object(Request))
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:112)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(object(RequestEvent), 'kernel.request', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
     (vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:126)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener->__invoke(object(RequestEvent), 'kernel.request', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
     (vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:264)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.request', object(RequestEvent))
     (vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:239)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->callListeners(array(object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.request', object(RequestEvent))
     (vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:73)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch(object(RequestEvent), 'kernel.request')
     (vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:168)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch(object(RequestEvent), 'kernel.request')
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:122)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:68)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:201)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (public/index.php:37)
```

Just to illustrate, the files are definitely still there. I'm unsure as to what is going on.

[Project main files including Controller and Utils](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w79KL.png)

routes.yaml only contains

```
#    path: /
#    controller: App\Controller\SMSLogProcessor::homepage
#
```

Could this be an issue with Symfony?

If you'd like to see any of the code I am happy to share. Thank you so much.

Comment: Routes should not point directly to a controller. Can you show the relevant route in either your `config/routes.{ext}` or in the annotations?

Comment: routes only has

#index:
#    path: /
#    controller: App\Controller\SMSLogProcessor::homepage
#

Comment: Please add the routing configurations to your question.